# Erro ao renderizar SectionList React Native

Tags: android, react, react-native

Estou tendo o seguinte erro no react-native ao tentar montar o componente que está sendo passado de uma tela para outra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o código para melhor compreender o procedimento.

**Codigo que busca os dados após o login**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native'
import { server, showError } from '../common'
import axios from 'axios'
let requestOptions = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}
export default class Auth extends Component {

  state = {
    logado: false,
    usuario: '',
    senha: '',
    obras: []
  }

  findObras = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${server}/obras`,
        data: {
          usuario: this.state.usuario,
        },
        headers: requestOptions
      });
      this.setState({ obras: JSON.stringify(res.data) })
      Alert.alert('Fazer Login', JSON.stringify(res.data))
    } catch (error) {
      showError(error)
    }
  }
  login = async () => {
    if (this.state.usuario === '') {
      Alert.alert('Fazer Login', "Para ter acesso ao sistema é preciso se logar")
    } else {
      try {
        const res = await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: `${server}/login`,
          data: {
            email: this.state.usuario,
            senha: this.state.senha
          },
          headers: requestOptions
        });
        this.findObras()
        this.setState({ logado: true })
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
          usuario: this.state.usuario,
          logado: this.state.logado,
          obras: this.state.obras
        })
      } catch (error) {
        showError(error)
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
          <Image resizeMode="contain" style={styles.logo} source={require('../../assets/logo-ageplan.png')} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <View style={styles.containerForm}>
            <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
              autoCorrect={false}
              keyboardType='email-address'
              returnKeyType="next"
              placeholder='Usuário'
              onChangeText={usuario => this.setState({ usuario })}
              placeholderTextColor='rgba(225,225,225,0.7)' />

            <TextInput style={styles.input}
              returnKeyType="go" ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
              placeholder='Senha'
              onChangeText={senha => this.setState({ senha })}
              placeholderTextColor='rgba(225,225,225,0.7)'
              secureTextEntry />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={this.login}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.buttonTextSenha}>Esqueceu a senha?</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
  }
}
// define your styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#696969',
  },
  loginContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  logo: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: 300,
    height: 100
  },
  title: {
    color: "#FFF",
    marginTop: 120,
    width: 180,
    textAlign: 'center',
    opacity: 10
  },
  containerForm: {
    padding: 20
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(225,225,225,0.2)',
    marginBottom: 10,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#fff'
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#2980b6',
    paddingVertical: 15
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: '700'
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#2980b6',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  buttonTextSenha: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: '700',
    marginTop: 20
  },

});
```

**Código onde acontece o erro**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  AsyncStorage,
  AppRegistry,
  SectionList
} from 'react-native'
import { server, showError } from '../common'
import axios from 'axios'
let requestOptions = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}


export default class Auth extends Component {

  state = {
    usuario: this.props.navigation.state.params.usuario,
    logado: this.props.navigation.state.params.logado,
    obras: this.props.navigation.state.params.obras
  }
  render() {
    Alert.alert('Bem Vindo', this.state.usuario)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          sections={this.state.obras}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 22
  },
  sectionHeader: {
    paddingTop: 2,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 2,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(247,247,247,1.0)',
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
})

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => SectionListBasics);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcos, você está tentando setar o estado antes do componente estar montado. Primeiro inicie o state com os atributos vazios. depois crie no componentDidMout o setState. Tipo assim:

```
componentDidMout() {
 const { usuario, logado, obras } = this.props.navigation.state.params
 this.setState({ usuario, logado, obras });
};
```

Só não tenho certeza sobre buscar os parametros assim. Lembro de algo como this.props.navigation.getParams('seu_parametro').
Mas tenta assim como eu te falei acima primeiro.

Answer (score 0):

Quando não renderizar mais o componente, ainda pode acontecer que this.setState () seja chamado se você tiver feito lógica de negócios assíncrona em seu componente e atualizado posteriormente o estado local do componente.

Você fez uma solicitação assíncrona para uma API, a requisição (Promise) ainda não foi resolvida, mas você desmontou o componente. Em seguida, a requisição é resolvida, e o this.setState () é chamado para definir o novo estado, mas atinge um componente não montado.